# An MS Access query that looks good to me but does not run

Tags: c#, ms-access

I am programmatically creating an MS Access query string. I can open the connection, but when I go to run the query to generate an OleDbReader, it bombs with no clear explanation. Here is the query string:

```
SELECT A.[ComponentCounter], B.[Page], B.[CellPosition] 
FROM ComponentText AS A 
INNER JOIN Connection AS B ON A.[ComponentCounter] = B.[CompCounter]
WHERE A.[TextId] = 160040 AND B.[ConnectionNumber] = 0 AND ( (Instr(A.[Text] , 'MAIN BUBBLE' ) = 1)  ) ;
```

I have checked that all columns exist in corresponding tables and are spelled correctly. The TextId and ConnectionNumber fields are both Number fields.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What specifically does *does not run* mean? Do you get an error message? If so, what is that message exactly? If not, what does *bombs* mean? We don't have your database, so we can't tell based on what you posted whether or not the columns are correctly spelled and reference the appropriate  tables, and you've not provided a clear problem description. Please read through [ask] and [mcve], and then come back and [edit] your question to be more specific about the problem so we can try to help you find a solution. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure if it will help. But it could be that you also should quote `Connection` with square brackets?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks LukStorms-- exactly right! All I had to do was enclose those two table names in the square brackets that only Access seems to need. It works now! I don't use Access a lot-- try to stay away from it-- so forgot how it needs to be babied sometimes.

Comment: It's probably more because `CONNECTION` is a reserved word in MS Access. Reference [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sql-reserved-words-b899948b-0e1c-4b56-9622-a03f8f07cfc8).  And you normally quote the names that are reserved words, or contain spaces, or some special characters.  Just to avoid problems.  If it's a name that only contains alphabet characters and numbers and isn't some reserved word, then the quoting is optional. Well, at least in most databases.